# Breaking up a single user input and storing it in two different variables. (Java)

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming, especially Java. I need to create a program that counts how many orders each entry at a restaurant gets ordered. The restaurant carries 3 entries, hamburgers, salad, and special.

I need to set up my program so that the user inputs, say, "hamburger 3", it would keep track of the number and add it up at the end. If the user inputs "quit", the program would quit.

```
System.out.println("Enter the type (special, salad, or hamburger) of entrée followed by the number, or quit to exit the program.");
```

I'm thinking about using a while loop, setting it so if the user input != to "quit", then it would run.

What's difficult for me is I don't know how to make my program take into account the two different parts of the user input, "hamburger 3" and sum up the number part at the end.

At the end, I want it to say something like "You sold X hamburgers, Y salads, and Z specials today."

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `String#split` using `" "` as the token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want three `int` variables to use as a running tally of the number of orders been made:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private int specials = 0;
    private int salads = 0;
    private int hamburger = 0;
```

You could then use a `do-while` loop to request information from the user...

```
String input = null;
do {
    //...
} while ("quite".equalsIgnoreCase(input));
```

Now, you need some way to ask the user for input.  You can use a `java.util.Scanner` easily enough for this.  See [the `Scanning` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//...
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the type (special, salad, or hamburger) of entrée followed by the number, or quit to exit the program.");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
```

Now you have the input from the user, you need to make some decisions.  You need to know if they entered valid input (an entree and an amount) as well as if they entered an available option...

```
// Break the input apart at the spaces...
String[] parts = input.split(" "); 
// We only care if there are two parts...
if (parts.length == 2) {
    // Process the parts...
} else if (parts.length == 0 || !"quite".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])) {
    System.out.println("Your selection is invalid");
}
```

Okay, so we can now determine if the user input meets or first requirement or not (`[text][space][text]`), now we need to determine if the values are actually valid...

First, lets check the quantity...

```
if (parts.length == 2) {
    // We user another Scanner, as this can determine if the String
    // is an `int` value (or at least starts with one)
    Scanner test = new Scanner(parts[1]);
    if (test.hasInt()) {
        int quantity = test.nextInt();
        // continue processing...
    } else {
        System.out.println(parts[1] + " is not a valid quantity");
    }
```

Now we want to check if the actually entered a valid entree...

```
if (test.hasInt()) {
    int quantity = test.nextInt();
    // We could use a case statement here, but for simplicity...
    if ("special".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])) {
        specials += quantity;
    } else if ("salad".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])) {
        salads += quantity;
    } else if ("hamburger".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])) {
        hamburger += quantity;
    } else {
        System.out.println(parts[0] + " is not a valid entree");
    }
```

Take a look at [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) and [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details.

You may also find [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) of some help.  Also, keep a copy of the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) at hand, it will make it eaiser to find references to the classes within the API

Comment: Thanks for such a quick/detailed answer. It's late so I'll try this tomorrow. The only problem is I'm taking a class and we haven't learned most of the methods you explained. I think the teacher expects me to do all this just using while and if statements...

Comment: Well, basically, that's all there is...I'd `Scanner` is about the only complicated part ;)

Answer (score 0):

These two methods should be what you're looking for.

For splitting: String.split(String regex)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

For parsing String into an Interger: Integer.parseInt(String s)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can split your strings using `input.split(" ")`. This method gives you two strings - two parts of the main string. The character you splitted with (`" "`) won't be found in the string anymore.

To then get an integer out of your string, you can use the static method `Integer.parseInt(inputPartWithCount)`.

I hope this helps!